Only printing content in a given environment
I have a text with some parts framed with mdframed and I want to show only these parts (my question is basically the opposite of this question). Using the package extract you can create a new file with only the content in a given environment. I would like to know if you can simply print the content contained in the mdframed environment without creating a new file.
\begin{document}
\usepackage{mdframed}

Content I don't want to be printed.

\begin{mdframed}
Content I do want to be printed.
\end{mdframed}

More content I don't want to be printed.
\end{document}


As a disclaimer, I am not familiar with how to do this, but an idea that comes to mind  would be to temporarily redefine that environment to call \end{comment} before running it, and then after, re-begin the comment. Then you could just enclose your document in comments. I'm not sure if this would work, but its what comes to mind. Welcome to TeX.SE, by the way!

Thanks for the idea.
